# possible to constrain output in generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface which defines various filtering on data (queries coming from EF4).

Interface method:

```
IQueryable<T> filter<T>() where T : class;
```

Now in a concrete implementation of that interface, I want to be able to do:

```
public IQueryable<T> filter<T>() {
  if (...) return query.OfType<Foo>().Take(100);
  if (...) return query.OfType<Bar>().Blah();
  // etc
}
```

But of course that doesn't work as the function signature expects `T` and not `Foo` or `Bar`. Is there some simple way to cast this output, or do I need to forgo the generic approach?

Comment: "do I need to forgo the generic approach?" doesn't make sense; you already have. You apparently care about `Foo`s and `Bar`s, but maybe not `Frob`s and `Grob`s. If your method isn't generically applicable, why make it generic?

Comment: How are you expecting to convert each `Foo` or `Bar` to a `T`?

Comment: @dlev: good point, but gotta have me some ``Frobs``. I guess I wanted to call filter<Foo>() which operates on the data and returns a subset. Since the data I'm using derives from a common class, maybe I'll just use that instead of ``T``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Foo` and `Bar` classes can both be cast as `T`, something like this would work:

```
public IQueryable<T> filter<T>() {
  if (...) return query.OfType<Foo>().Take(100).Cast<T>();
  if (...) return query.OfType<Bar>().Blah().Cast<T>();
  // etc
}
```

However, you need to make sure that they can both be cast as `T`, or else you'll obviously get InvalidCastExceptions.  So you would be well-served to make sure `T` can be cast to either type by changing your declaration to someting along the lines of:

```
public IQueryable<T> filter<T>() where T : IFooBar
```

Where `IFooBar` is the base class/interface for both `Foo` and `Bar`

Comment: you must be very proud of yourself, because today you beat The Skeet to a green tick...